# RecyclerView onClick gives wrong item

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` that shows a list of student details. The issue I face is when I click on the first item it returns the data of the second item.
I believe that it has something to do with `getAdapterPosition()`, but I'm not sure.

In this case, it returns the Roll No. of the second student(item) when the first student is selected.

Any help is appreciated

---

**RecyclerViewAdapter**

```
public class StudentAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<StudentAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    Context context;
    public List<StudentDataModel> dataModels;
    public StudentDataModel dataAdapter;

    public StudentAdapter(List<StudentDataModel> getDataAdapter, Context context){
        super();
        this.dataModels = getDataAdapter;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.student, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final StudentAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
        dataAdapter =  dataModels.get(position);        
        viewHolder.NameStudentCard.setText(dataAdapter.getName());
        viewHolder.RankStudentCard.setText(dataAdapter.getRank());
        viewHolder.RollStudentCard.setText(dataAdapter.getRoll());

        viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                notifyDataSetChanged();                
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Tapped on" + dataAdapter.getRoll(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //Here it returns the Roll No. of the second student(item) in the recyclerView.                
                Intent intent = new Intent (v.getContext(), StudentDetailsActivity.class);                
                v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        public TextView NameStudentCard;
        public TextView RankStudentCard;
        public TextView RollStudentCard;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            NameStudentCard=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
            RankStudentCard=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewRank);
            RollStudentCard =(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewEmployeeID);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dataModels.size();
    }

}
```

Comment: Why you are notifying data change onClick event?? Remove notifyDataSetChanged(); and check.

Comment: why are you calling notifyDataSetChanged()? Does the first element display the right data in the recyclerview? I see that you're setting the roll in the textview of the card, is that working failing too? or is it just on the click listener?

Comment: first of all change the arg of onBindViewHolder `final int position` to `int postition`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, because you are declaring object as global object. So it is getting update with last visible row's object, because  `onBindViewHolder()` gets called for each visible row sequentially. So it will work properly only for last visible row.

So you need to declare it inside method :

comment this :

```
   // public StudentDataModel dataAdapter;
```

declare it here :

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final StudentAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {

   final StudentDataModel dataAdapter =  dataModels.get(position); // add this here

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class StudentAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<StudentAdapter.ViewHolder> {

Context context;

public List<StudentDataModel> dataModels;


public StudentAdapter(List<StudentDataModel> getDataAdapter, Context context){

super();

this.dataModels = getDataAdapter;
this.context = context;
}

public StudentDataModel dataAdapter;


@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.student, parent, false);

    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);

    return viewHolder;

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final StudentAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {

     dataAdapter =  dataModels.get(position);

    viewHolder.NameStudentCard.setText(dataAdapter.getName());

    viewHolder.RankStudentCard.setText(dataAdapter.getRank());

    viewHolder.RollStudentCard.setText(dataAdapter.getRoll());




}




@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    return dataModels.size();
}


class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public TextView NameStudentCard;
    public TextView RankStudentCard;
    public TextView RollStudentCard;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {

        super(itemView);

        NameStudentCard=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
        RankStudentCard=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewRank);
        RollStudentCard =(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewEmployeeID);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Tapped on" + dataModels.get(getAdapterPosition()).getRoll(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 

                Intent intent = new Intent (v.getContext(), StudentDetailsActivity.class);

                v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code..
make interface into adapter class for click handling like this way..

```
 onItemClickListner onItemClickListner;

public void setOnItemClickListner(RecyclerViewAdpater.onItemClickListner onItemClickListner) {
    this.onItemClickListner = onItemClickListner;
}

 public interface onItemClickListner{
    void onItemClick(String data); // pass any data;
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ItemViewHolder holder, int position) {
    // below code handle click event on recycler view item.
    String data=mStringList.get(position);
    holder.textView.setText(data);
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            onItemClickListner.onItemClick(data); //pass your data;
        }
    });
}
```

after that bind adapter into recyclerview and adapter not null then called below code..

```
    recyclerViewAdpater.setOnItemClickListner(new RecyclerViewAdpater.onItemClickListner() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(String data) {
            // perform your operation.
            recyclerViewAdpater.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```